# Can I configure multiple certificates on my GKE/Istio Gateway?

Tags: istio, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using the prepackaged [Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview), which comes with a pre-configured ingress gateway that takes a single SSL certificate.

Is there a way to add additional certificates to Google's standard configuration which will survive reset by their configuration tool and persist through upgrades?

The Istio docs [describe](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-multiple-hosts) how to specify multiple certificates if installing the ingress gateway yourself.  I could do this if I configured a separate ingress gateway, but would like to use the default one if I could.  Google's [docs](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview#modifying_control_plane_settings) do not list certificates as a modifiable property.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [post](https://medium.com/@prune998/istio-1-0-2-envoy-cert-manager-lets-encrypt-for-tls-certificate-merge-7a774bff66c2) from `Medium` which explains how to use multiple Certificates for `Istio` through `Cert-Manager`, `Let's Encrypt for TLS` and `Certificate Merge`.

Could you please take a look at the post and let me know if it's useful?

Comment: Very interesting post, and creative idea.  Unfortunately it requires building an altered version of the Cert-Manager component, so would be harder than setting up my own ingress gateway.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to hear that this workaround isn't useful. However I found a very interesting [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/istio-users/-MRvZsgyrFc) and I think that could be helful to solve your issue.